# Implementation of Encryption in web application

Tags: web, encryption

I am working on security implementation in web application. I have developed a node.js web server and a clients in HTML for displaying the data to end users. I want that the data shown to the clients be encrypted and sent from server. I though that i will encrypt the data using AES at node.js server and decrypt it at client. But decryption at client will need keys to be stored in the client application which is not recommended. I read about SubtleCrypto interface of WebCrypto API. But these are not supported in all browsers. Now I am not able to understand that how I implement encryption and decryption of data in my web application. Where should I keep the keys. Please advice any suitable architecture and technology so that I should be able to serve encrypted data to the clients without compromise of keys. Please suggest if symmetric or asymmetric encryption algorithm will be suitable for my scenario.

Comment: This question may be much too broad for this site. Just a hint regarding the storage of keys: if you want to avoid a storage the user needs to give a passphrase for (symmetric) encryption on the server and needs to enter the same passphrase on the client for decryption. The key derivation from the passohrase is usually done with a PBKDF2- or Argon2-algorithm. For both, you need to find libraries that are supported on your browsers. A second note: if you are aware that WebCrypto is not supported on ALL browsers it could be a hard job to find libraries that run on - ever older - browsers.

Comment: In order to suggest a good approach, we would need to better understand the requirements and the context. Who may or may not see the data? Is the user authenticated? What are the attacks you want to defend against? At the moment it sounds as if a regular *https* connection should do the trick.

Comment: @Codo  I want that the data should not be read by intruders in transit. The clients are to be browsed at restricted location or at the clients the user will be first required to authenticate using a password.

Comment: If so, *https* is sufficient. It cannot be read in transit. Your efforts should therefore go into properly authentication users and ensuring that the request is coming from a restricted location.

Comment: I second what @Codo said, it's really important to understand that anything in the client's environment is essentially compromised (e.g. think a user installs a Google plugin that scrapes their entire javascript); if you're only worried about data in transit, use HTTPS